# How to add typescript and react together in jsfiddle?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsfiddle

I want to add Typescript and React together to jsfiddle.

Sample JSFiddle. I have declared interface from typescript.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/ilikeflex/r2uws1ez/54/`
```

Notice language in drop down

[image: Notice language in drop down]

If i select, typescript from drop down nothing work. Nothing is displayed.
But if i changed to 'React', then content is displayed.
Displayed Content is very basic. It has three buttons.

How to use both libraries together.?

Comment: You can't in jsfiddle. You can in `codesandbox.io`, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is simple, there's no way you can use typescript with react in jsfiddle. Though there are many alternatives such as playcode.io and codesandbox.io